# bash function conflict with alias

Tags: linux, bash, sh

How could I detect aliases before define same name function in bash script file(this file will be sourced in another script)?

Something like meta-programming in bash (define another name function if this name is already taken by aliases?)

```
$ source t.sh
$ alert 'test'
test
$ type alert
alert is a function
alert () 
{ 
    echo -n "$@"
}

$ alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i error'
$ source t.sh
bash: t.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: t.sh: line 1: `alert() { echo "$@"; }'
$ type alert
alert is aliased to `notify-send --urgency=low -i error'

$ cat t.sh
alert() { echo "$@"; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if alias alert 2> /dev/null; then
    echo "'alert' already an alias"
else
    source t.sh
fi
```

The `alias` command exists with non-zero status if its single argument is not an alias.

Comment: `unalias alert` will remote the alias, so I can use the function with same name(not the alias).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to. Aliases by default are not expanded in non-interactive shells.

Comment: But what to do if it is used in interactive shell?

Comment: That's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `which <name>` returns 0 if  `name` is an alias.

So to check if `custom_name` is already used you can do:

```
if [ $(which custom_name >/dev/null; echo $?) -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Already aliased"
    return 1
else
    echo "Free to use"
    return 0
fi
```

---

Note: This will not check if there is a bash function called `custom_name` in the current shell.

Comment: `man which` say nothing about alias. `which` return 1 when alias exists already.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of which you're using and on what distribution, but `which untar` returns `0` for me and I have `alias untar='tar -xvf'` in my bashrc

Comment: `which --version` give nothing. This `which` comes from debianutils              4.4.